# How to remove Google Maps route polylines with iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm drawing polylines of a route using Google maps iOS SDK:

```
func drawPolygon(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    googleMaps.isHidden = false
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=KEYHERE") else {
        return
    }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                if json["status"] as! String == "OK"{
                    let routes = json["routes"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        for route in routes{
                            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"] as! [String:String]
                            let points = routeOverviewPolyline["points"]
                            self.path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)!
                            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: self.path)
                            self.drawPath(polyline: polyline)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
    
}
```

Draw polylines func:

```
private func drawPath(polyline : GMSPolyline){
    
    //DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        polyline.strokeWidth = 6.0
        polyline.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8465872407, blue: 0.7545004487, alpha: 1)
        polyline.map = self.googleMaps
        self.addMarker()
        // let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
        // self.googleMaps.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 50.0))
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: self.fromLoc!, coordinate: self.toLoc!)
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 170, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30))
        self.googleMaps.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 20.0))
        self.googleMaps.animate(toZoom: 10)
        self.googleMaps.animate(toViewingAngle: 30)
        self.googleMaps!.moveCamera(update)
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.003, target: self, selector: #selector(animatePolylinePath), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    //}
}
```

The route and polylines are working absolutely fine. I was thinking to remove polylines as the user passes the line on the route for a better experience. I'm using Swift 5 and wondering if anyone can tell me if it's possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

```
internal weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

/// Clear mapView Polylines
internal func clearPath() {
    let line = GMSPolyline()
    line.map = mapView
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Comment: can you please Explain Your answer Please?

Comment: I think with your answer it will remove all the polylines. The polyline is made up of line segments. My question was in relation to how to delete polylines are the current location moves from the line.